# Access violation while requesting memory in getmem.inc

Tags: debugging, crash, c++builder, windbg

I'm trying to understand an access violation  (c0000005) in my C++ program build with "Codegear C++ Builder 2009"
I have catched the access violation with procdump and analysed it with WinDbg.
Here is the information i gathered with WinDbg.:

Callstack:

```
  # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
>00 0d98f960 004b3728 0001e000 108c6af0 0001e000 MMIServer!SystemSysGetMem$qqri+0x316 [GETMEM.INC @ 2015] 
 01 0d98f978 004b443f 0d98f988 004890b8 108d5b20 MMIServer!SysReallocMem+0x2dc [GETMEM.INC @ 3404] 
 02 0d98f998 0048910c 0d98f9f4 108c6af0 00482730 MMIServer!ReallocMem+0x13 [System.pas @ 3521] 
 03 0d98f9ac 00488a40 09b60b58 108c6af0 0000f000 MMIServer!TMemoryStreamWrite+0x30 [Classes.pas @ 6181] 
 04 0d98f9bc 00488b0e 0d98fa04 00488b3c 0d98f9f4 MMIServer!ClassesTStreamWriteBuffer+0x18 [Classes.pas @ 5789] 
 05 0d98f9f4 0046d910 0000fc40 00000000 0d98fa10 MMIServer!ClassesTStreamCopyFrom+0xae [Classes.pas @ 5814] 
 06 0d98fa38 0046dc85 0d98faec 0046dcec 0d98fad8 MMIServer!TOPToSoapDomConvertDOMToStream+0x80 [..\..\Patches\BDS2009\TByteDynArrayThroughSOAP\OPToSOAPDomConv.pas @ 895] 
 07 0d98fad8 0052c272 01ca3930 10680b90 10d4daa8 MMIServer!TOPToSoapDomConvertMakeResponse+0x31d [..\..\Patches\BDS2009\TByteDynArrayThroughSOAP\OPToSOAPDomConv.pas @ 987] 
 08 0d98fb94 0052eff9 0d98fcfb 10680b90 10680870 MMIServer!TSoapPascalInvokerInvoke+0x34e [SOAPPasInv.pas @ 230] 
 09 0d98fc24 00526edb 0d98fcfb 10680b90 10680870 MMIServer!THTTPSoapPascalInvokerDispatchSOAP+0x20d [soaphttppasinv.pas @ 82] 
 0a 0d98fd2c 00566d5b 10d1fee0 0d98fd6c 00566d83 MMIServer!THTTPSoapDispatcherDispatchRequest+0x28b [WebBrokerSOAP.pas @ 223] 
 0b 0d98fd5c 00566e88 00000000 10d1fee0 0d98fda4 MMIServer!DispatchHandler+0x8b [HTTPApp.pas @ 1511] 
 0c 0d98fd98 00567063 0046b308 0d98fdb0 0046b321 MMIServer!TCustomWebDispatcherDispatchAction+0xf0 [HTTPApp.pas @ 1546] 
 0d 0d98fe10 0046b205 08dae450 02e3f360 09b21b70 MMIServer!TCustomWebDispatcherHandleRequest+0xb [HTTPApp.pas @ 1594] 
 0e 0d98fe28 005b6e1f 08dae450 0d98fe40 005b6e43 MMIServer!TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridgeDoCommandGet+0x2d [..\..\Patches\Indy10\IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas @ 964] 
 0f 0d98fefc 005d86be 01c23370 005c7939 005c7783 MMIServer!IdcustomhttpserverTIdCustomHTTPServerDoExecute$qqrp20IdcontextTIdContext+0x683
 10 0d98ff70 0048da71 0d98ff84 0048da7b 0d98ffa0 MMIServer!IdcontextTIdContextRun$qqrv+0x12
 11 0d98ffa0 004b63f2 0d98ffdc 004b5e74 0d98ffb4 MMIServer!ThreadProc+0x45 [Classes.pas @ 10892] 
 12 0d98ffb4 7c80b729 08b3e090 030afabc 00000000 MMIServer!ThreadWrapper+0x2a [System.pas @ 13819]
```

CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\source\Win32\rtl\sys\getmem.inc:

```
 2004 @GotBinAndGroup:
 2005   {ebx = block size, ecx = bin number, edx = group number}
 2006   push esi
 2007   push edi
 2008   {Get a pointer to the bin in edi}
 2009   lea edi, [MediumBlockBins + ecx * 8]
 2010   {Get the free block in esi}
 2011   mov esi, TMediumFreeBlock[edi].NextFreeBlock
 2012   {Remove the first block from the linked list (LIFO)}
 2013   mov eax, TMediumFreeBlock[esi].NextFreeBlock
 2014   mov TMediumFreeBlock[edi].NextFreeBlock, eax
>2015   mov TMediumFreeBlock[eax].PreviousFreeBlock, edi
 2016   {Is this bin now empty?}
 2017   cmp edi, eax
 2018   jne @MediumBinNotEmptyForMedium
 2019   {eax = bin group number, ecx = bin number, edi = @bin, esi = free block, ebx = block size}
 2020   {Flag this bin as empty}
 2021   mov eax, -2
 2022   rol eax, cl
 2023   and dword ptr [MediumBlockBinBitmaps + edx * 4], eax
 2024   jnz @MediumBinNotEmptyForMedium
 2025   {Flag the group as empty}
 2026   btr MediumBlockBinGroupBitmap, edx
 2027 @MediumBinNotEmptyForMedium:
```

Disassembly:

```
 004b31d4 56              push    esi
 004b31d5 57              push    edi
 004b31d6 8d3ccd00be3201  lea     edi,MMIServer!NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention+0x1ef (0132be00)[ecx*8]
 004b31dd 8b7704          mov     esi,dword ptr [edi+4]
 004b31e0 8b4604          mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+4]
 004b31e3 894704          mov     dword ptr [edi+4],eax
>004b31e6 8938            mov     dword ptr [eax],edi  ds:0023:00000000=????????
 004b31e8 39c7            cmp     edi,eax
 004b31ea 7517            jne     MMIServer!SystemSysGetMem$qqri+0x333 (004b3203)
 004b31ec b8feffffff      mov     eax,0FFFFFFFEh
 004b31f1 d3c0            rol     eax,cl
 004b31f3 21049580bd3201  and     dword ptr MMIServer!NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention+0x16f (0132bd80)[edx*4],eax
 004b31fa 7507            jne     MMIServer!SystemSysGetMem$qqri+0x333 (004b3203)
 004b31fc 0fb3157cbd3201  btr     dword ptr [MMIServer!NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention+0x16b (0132bd7c)],edx
```

My understanding of this piece of code of getmem.inc is:

1. There is a double-linked list of free memory blocks.
2. One block is taken from this list.
3. The Double Linked List is reconnected.

In drawing:

```
|----------|--------------------->|----------|--------------------->|----------|
|          | NextFreeBlock        |          | NextFreeBlock        |          |
|  132d408 |                      | 11290132 |                      | 00000000 |
|          |<---------------------|          |<---------------------|          |
|----------|    PreviousFreeBlock |----------|    PreviousFreeBlock |----------|
     ^                                  ^                                 ^
     |                                  |                                 |
    edi                                esi                               eax


|----------|--------------------->|----------|                      |----------|
|          | NextFreeBlock        |          |                      |          |
|  132d408 |                      | 00000000 |                      | 11290132 |
|          |<---------------------|          |                      |          |
|----------|    PreviousFreeBlock |----------|                      |----------|
     ^                                  ^                                 ^
     |                                  |                                 |
    edi                                eax                               esi
```

Some registers:

```
eax 0
ebx 1e030
ecx 2c1
edx 16
edi 132d408
esi 11290132

ebp 1e000
eip 4b31e6
esp d98f958
```

There is a NULL pointer in the Double Linked Lists of the free memory blocks.
When writing the PreviousFreeBlock to this address the access violation occurred.

How can there be a NULL pointer in the Double Linked Lists of the free memory blocks?
Was the memory already corrupted?
Have anyone experienced the same problem in getmem.inc?
What can i do to investigate this crash further?

Comment: Buffer overflow, buffer underrun, writing to a pointer that pointed into that linked list...?

Comment: Without a [mcve], there is really no way for anyone to troubleshoot the issue or diagnose what happened. All I can gleam from this info is that Indy's `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` is being used to call into some other user-defined SOAP code that is calling `TStream.CopyFrom()` to copy data into a `TMemoryStream`, and the stream is failing to allocate new memory due to potential corruption in the linked list of memory blocks owned by the RTL's Memory Manager.